# Cannot find the declaration of element 'Templates

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

XML input

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Templates>
    <Template>
        <ObjTmplId>1</ObjTmplId>
        <AttTmplId>1</AttTmplId>
        <Is_Ingest>0</Is_Ingest>
        <System_Name>DNC</System_Name>
        <System_Category>ALL</System_Category>
        <System_Class>hazarda</System_Class>
        <System_Table>BD000</System_Table>
        <System_Attribute>cod</System_Attribute>
        <System_Value>-32768</System_Value>
    </Template>
</Templates>
```

xsd doc

```xml
<?xml version= '1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8' ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://cfpe/export/objects" xmlns="http://cfpe/export  /objects" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xsd:element name="Templates" type="TemplateListType" />

        <xsd:complexType name="TemplateListType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="Template" type="TemplateType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="TemplateType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="ObjTmplId" type="xsd:integer"/>
                  <xsd:element name="AttTmplId" type="xsd:integer"/>
                  <xsd:element name="Is_Ingest" type="xsd:integer"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Category" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Class" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Table" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Attribute" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="System_Value" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="Condition" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

The xsd could not validate the xml. I was trying to have an xml file that's valid with the xsd. I have attached both the xml and xsd docs

Comment: The Prefix "xsd" For Element "xsd:element" Is Not Bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct xml is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Templates xmlns:ns1="http://cfpe/export/objects">
    <ns1:Template>
        <ns1:ObjTmplId/>
        <ns1:AttTmplId/>
        <ns1:Is_Ingest/>
        <ns1:System_Name/>
        <ns1:System_Category/>
        <ns1:System_Class/>
        <ns1:System_Table/>
        <ns1:System_Attribute/>
        <ns1:System_Value/>
        <ns1:Condition/>
    </ns1:Template>
</ns1:Templates>
```

i validated by [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)